# Python tkinter saving to txt creates unusual empty row

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, save, txt

I am transferring an input in first listbox to second listbox. As you see in the first picture below, When I select "dd" in the first listbox, and press the "Yapıldı" button, it transferred to listbox below (second picture).

[first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deUlK.png)

[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwkVm.png)

When I save second listbox to a file.txt. An error occurs. Before transferring "dd", my file.txt is like that:

```
a
b
```

After transferring "dd" and saving it to file.txt file. My txt file is like that:

```
a

b
dd
```

An empty row occurs in between a and b. Here is my code for transferring, and saving.

```
def select():
    textentry2.insert(END, textentry.get(ANCHOR))
    textentry.delete(ANCHOR)
```

**Note: textentry2 = second listbox widget, textentry =first listbox widget**

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.close()
with open("file.txt", "r+") as file2:
    file2.write("\n".join(textentry2.get("0", "end")))
```

I tried to clear my file.txt before saving, and write my second listbox to empty file.txt but still same one empty row error happens. I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: You don't have to close a file using `with` statement it does that automatically, also why are You joining what You get from textentry with newline?

Comment: Yes, I tried without it but still same error

Comment: with open("file.txt", "w") as file1:
            data = textentry2.get("0", "end")
            file1.write(data) I have changed like this but it gives me an error that TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple

Comment: `with open("file.txt", "w") as file:` then use `data = textentry2.get("0", "end")` then `file.write("\n".join(data))`.

Comment: If you use `"\n".join(...).split("\n")` it should remove the new line that is at the end.

Comment: I used file.write("\n".join(data)) at the end but when I add new input to my listbox and save it, my file.txt file creates a new row(it is empty) between row 1 and row 2. Like in the example above in my topic (a bdd-> think it vertically)

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.  How do you insert the data into `textentry`?  Try printing out the data before saving to file and see whether the file content matches the print out.

Comment: There is no problem with the printed output. When I am saving it to txt file, that extra one row between first and second row occurs. I don’t understand why

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I fixed the function that opens the file.txt . Problem solved, if you interested here is the code:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file2:
    data2 = file2.read()
textentry2.delete("0", "end")
for line in data2.split("\n"):
    textentry2.insert("end", line)
```